# Force clients to use proxy

Tags: proxy

Here's my network configuration:

[My network configuration http://daveden.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/network-configuration.png](http://daveden.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/network-configuration.png)

The proxy server is running Ubuntu with Squid on port 3128 and DansGuardian on port 8080.

I'd like to force all clients to use the proxy server - specifically, port 8080 - for any TCP/UDP access. However, I don't want to transparently redirect.

How do I do this? Can I just drop packets if the client isn't configured to use the proxy server on port 8080?

I'd like whatever system I come up with to work on the proxy server itself as well. It's the only desktop computer in the house, so it'd be nice if I could allow people in my household to use it but still know that they're protected.

Comment: It may be a question for http://serverfault.com/ !

Comment: You either run a transparent proxy or block web traffic and manually setup the proxy on all clients.

Comment: Why don't you want to transparently redirect? Seems the easiest solution. You could implement a captive portal to explain users what to do, and thus avoid the "The Internet is not working for me!" syndrome, but why suffer needlessly?

Comment: Closed as off topic??? The guys at Server Fault said I should ask here!

Comment: The reason I don't want to transparently redirect is because that doesn't work for HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

- Use something like [WCCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Cache_Communication_Protocol) and function [transparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Implementation_methods)
- Be an [inline proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy), as it seems you are now.
- Use [WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) to send the devices to a box hosting your [PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file.
- Manually specify the proxy in your clients.

However, this all depends on what you're exactly running, and if your devices support it (Can blenders handle PAC files?).  If possible, I suggest using WPAD, but you should be aware of [MITM vulnerabilities](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2012-07&post=WPAD-Man-in-the-Middle).

Also, to address your question about dropping TCP/UDP packets which aren't proxied, just drop everything that doesn't have a source of your proxy, at any point after the ingress interface of the proxy.  Unfortunately, if you want to do this with a separate device, that device will have to reside between your proxy and modem.

You can also set your proxy up to do it by either using [iptables](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030213.html) on your proxy egress interface, or you could just not route traffic outbound for other internal devices... But the second solution would also extend past TCP/IP to include ICMP, IP Protocols, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect packet to send them to your proxy

This method is called *transparent proxy*

You may find some cookbooks there:

- [TLDP.org - Transparent Proxy with Linux and Squid mini-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html)
- [DDWrt - Transparent web proxy](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy)

Comment: The reason I don't want to transparently redirect is because that doesn't work for HTTPS.

Comment: Take a look there: http://serverfault.com/questions/369829/setting-up-a-transparent-ssl-proxy